# asp.net image display as a percentage

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that accepts image uploads up to 4MB.  The images can be as small as 100x100 or even as large as 1900 x 1200.  I'm using a pop-up window to display the uploaded image.

The problem is that I want to scale the larger images programmatically (but not modify the image itself).  I want to display the large images at 80% (or 60% or whatever) if possible.  I've seen browsers display an image at XX % then when you click on an icon, then the image will be displayed at 100%.

That's the effect I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the code located http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx

Then I would onclick of an icon pass the percentage value to that function and the render the result.

Comment: I ended up going that route anyways around the time I rechecked this again.